# Web Scraping of Metacritic: Reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

¿I've developed a web scraper for Metacritic where I get the reviews, but now I have to change the way I scrape and I have to have in one place the good reviews(8-10), neutral reviews(5-8) and bad reviews (1-5). How should I do so when I scrape I separate my reviews in those 3 categories!?

```
urls = ['https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/league-of-legends/user-reviews']

def scrape_metacritic(self, urls):
    """
    Public method that extracts all the reviews given a list of Metacritic URLS
    :param urls:
    :return:
    """
    data = []
    for url in urls:
        start = 0
        next = 1
        while start < next:
            html = self.__make_request(url + f'user-reviews?page={str(start)}')
            blocks = self.__div_blocks(html)
            reviews = self.__get_comments(blocks)
            if len(reviews) is 0:
                start = next
            else:
                for review in reviews:
                    data.append(review)
                start += 1
                next += 1
    return data
```

What would the function be?

Comment: Please, clarify what you want to achieve. Counting the number of reviews for each of the three categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're best off with a dictionary of lists.. something like

```
data = {'bad': [], 'neutral': [], 'good': []}
```

then when you are iterating through the reviews, you append to the proper list.

```
if review.score < 8 and review.score > 4:
    data['neutral'].append(review)
```